# Update scrollbar in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, scrollbar

I'm programming something in python and I need to create a scrollbar that updates when new widgets are added to the window. I don't know how to do this and I haven't found the answer in any place. Is there a command for this? This is my code right now.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

my_canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
my_canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand = 1)

my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = "vertical", command = my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

my_frame = tk.LabelFrame(my_canvas, width = my_canvas.winfo_width())
my_frame.grid_propagate(0)
my_frame.pack()

for i in range(10):
    my_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text = "Label")
    my_label.pack()

my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), width = 600, anchor = "nw", window = my_frame)

def create_label(scroll, canv, fram):
    my_label = tk.Label(fram, text="Label")
    my_label.pack()
   


my_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text = "Button", command = lambda: create_label(my_scrollbar, my_canvas, my_frame))
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `<Configure>` event of the inner frame. That event fires whenever the frame changes size.

```
def adjust_scrollregion(event):
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
my_frame.bind("<Configure>", adjust_scrollregion)
```

---

Unrelated to the question that was asked... calling `my_frame.grid_propagate(0)` is pointless since you use `pack` inside of `my_frame`.